# CSS transform skew glitch on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, transform, skew

I have some buttons and if I use transform skew a glitch appear between them, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

This is the CSS:

```
.btn-category {
    height: 100%;
    transform: skew(20deg);
    border: .5rem solid $body-bg;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

If I remove the borders it's not visible, but I think is just because it has the same color as the button.

Is there a solution without removing borders?

Thank you in advance for your answer.